# URL Rewrite create subdomain in cakephp

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite, cakephp-2.2

I am using **Cakephp** framework 2.2.2.

I want to create a personalized URL for the user. For example, if a user enters **username=pragnesh**,
then they can access my site like: http://pragnesh.mylocalhost.com, same as in blinksale.com

---

My URL: **http://mylocalhost.com/test/users/front_home**

I want to access it at: **http://test.mylocalhost.com/users/front_home**

My URL: **http://mylocalhost.com/test/setting/pages**
can be accessed at: **http://test.mylocalhost.com/setting/pages**

any URL: **http://mylocalhost.com/test/xxxxx/xxxxx**
can be accessed at : **http://test.mylocalhost.com/xxxxx/xxxxx**

---

**OR**

---

URL: **http://mylocalhost.com/users/front_home?site=test**

I want to access it at: **http://test.mylocalhost.com/users/front_home**

My URL: **http://mylocalhost.com/setting/pages?site=test**
can be accessed at: **http://test.mylocalhost.com/setting/pages**

any URL: **http://mylocalhost.com/xxxxx/xxxxx?site=test**
can be accessed at: **http://test.mylocalhost.com/xxxxx/xxxxx**

---

My question may be possible duplicate of [My cakephp 2.2 site not working on subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20328636/my-cakephp-2-2-site-not-working-on-subdomain)
but there is no answer posted.

I have tried below code in **\app\webroot.htaccess**

[htaccess subdomai (part 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649890/htaccess-subdomai-part-2)

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^([^&]*&)*site=[^&]+
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mylocalhost.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.mylocalhost.com
RewriteRule ^([^\.]*).php$ /$1.php?user=%1 [QSA,L,R]
```

[URL rewrite for Subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25938781/url-rewrite-for-subdomain)

```
# capture first part of host name
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.mylocalhost\.com$ [NC]
# make sure site= query parameter isn't there
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)site= [NC]
# rewrite to current URI?site=backererence #1 from host name
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?site=%1 [L,QSA]
```

but both not working for me.

my root .htaccss file is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
  RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

\app.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

\app\webroot.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

**Virtual Host in httpd.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
   DocumentRoot "E:/xampp/htdocs/bsale"
   ServerName mylocalhost.com
   ServerAlias *.mylocalhost.com
   <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/bsale">
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**HOST FILE**

```
127.0.0.1   mylocalhost.com
127.0.0.1   *.mylocalhost.com
```

Comment: What is DocumentRoot of your test subdomain? Can you also post `VirtualHost` entry of `test` subdomain from Apache config?

Comment: document root is mylocalhost, i don't have access to hosting files

Comment: `DocumentRoot` needs to be full filesystem path and you need to know exact `DocumentRoot` for both root domain and `test` sub domain.

Comment: can I post httd.conf file for localhost where i have created alias/virtual host of mylocalhost.com?

Comment: @anubhava, can I do same on local server with creating alias?

Comment: Not using `alias` but using `VirtualHost` you can create `test.localhost` and `localhost` host entries on your local Apache config.

Comment: <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "E:/xampp/htdocs/bsale"
    ServerName mylocalhost.com
    ServerAlias *.mylocalhost.com
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/bsale">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


added in host file C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
127.0.0.1 mylocalhost.com
127.0.0.1 *.mylocalhost.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62957/discussion-between-pragnesh-chauhan-and-anubhava).

Comment: So `E:/xampp/htdocs/bsale` is common `DocumentRoot` for both main domain and test sub-domain?

Comment: yes, `E:/xampp/htdocs/bsale` is common DocumentRoot

Comment: I have created replica of blinksale.com where they can create personalize url
and access link like pragneshc.blinksale.com or test.blinksale.com

Comment: ok so what URL is causing problem for you now or what rewrite isn't working for you from above rules?

Comment: yes, it is not working with above examples

Comment: If you mean this: `if user enter username=pragnesh then they can access my site like http://pragnesh.mylocalhost.com` then I think you're mistaken as subdomain creation cannot happen on-the-fly from rewrite rules.

Comment: ok, can you please show me how i can do this

Comment: See I am not a server admin but as per my knowledge subdomains are not registered/created on the fly. They need to be registered with a hosting provider first.

Answer (score 1):

You can leave your .htaccess as in the default 
cakephp/.htaccess
cakephp/app/.htaccess
cakephp/app/webroot/.htaccess

You will need the virtual host like now have pointing at your app.

What you really need to look at is the app/Config/routes.php

take a look at the line that says:

```
CakePlugin::routes();
```

So, before that moment you can do anything you need (with routes).
Lets imagine a user johndoe has http://johndoe.yourapp.com/

Get the subdomain from the url, something like this:

```
array_shift((explode(".",'subdomain.my.com')));
```

using:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']


Router::connect('/users/front_home', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'front_home', $yourSubDomain));
```

Or just leave the router alone and detect the subdomain in your AppController, and use it anywhere in your app.